# How are edge angles calculated?

Tags: edges, units

I am curious how "Edge Angles" are calculated in Blender. In the picture below, the angle reads under 90 degrees even though it looks greater.

[image]

Comment: It's the angle between the face's normal vectors I think, which looks like about 45 degrees in your picture. Do you have some king of transform applied to the mesh?

Comment: @scurest: your comment sounds reasonable, but why does it show 87 degrees if you are talking about 45 degrees? :D

Comment: @Chris could there be an object-level scale on this, as scurest suggests?  From experiments only (I wish I was better at searching the code) the angle looks like `arccos(face1normal.dot (face2normal))`

Comment: @Robin Betts: oooops - i am very sorry for my limited knowledge - I didn’t even realize that  so i obviously have still to learn a lot here….…sorry scurest!!!